# Android dump file is 0 bytes

Tags: android, adb

I used the cmd 'adb shell am dumpheap com.xxx.xxx /data/local/tmp/com_xxx_xxx.hprof' to get the dumpheap file. But when i execute this cmd, i found the hprof file is 0 bytes. I don't know why? The device is a real phone witch had been rooted.

---